# Melhorando esquema de paginação - PHP e Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, paginação

No site que assumi de um cliente, algumas páginas possuem esquema de paginação. Por exemplo, uma página de notícias que mostra registro de 100 notícias publicadas aparecem 7 notícias por página. A paginação vai me mostrar do 1 ao 15. Eis o código pré-definido da paginação:

```
<?php if(@$data['quantidade_paginas'] > 1){;?>
<div class="blocoPaginacao">
<div class="paginacao">
    <span pg="anterior" class="btnSetaVoltar" style="opacity: 0"></span>
    <span pg="anterior" class="linkControle font12" style="opacity: 0"> ANTERIOR </span>
    <ul class="btsPaginacao">
        <?php for($i=1; $i<=$data['quantidade_paginas']; $i++){ ?>
        <li>
            <span pg="<?php echo $i?>" pagina_="<?php echo $i?>" class="btnPaginar<?php echo ($i==1 ? ' Sel' : ''); ?>"> <?php echo $i?> </span>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <span pg="proxima" class="linkControle font12"> PRÓXIMA </span>
    <span pg="proxima" class="btnSetaAvancar"></span> 
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="total_paginas" value="<?php echo $i-1?>">
<input type="hidden" id="pagina_atual" value="1">
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

O problema é se eu tiver umas 50  páginas. O esquema de paginação vai me mostrar 50 números de página pra eu poder escolher. Eu queria que só aparecesse do 1 ao 10, por exemplo. E clicando a partir do 10, por exemplo, começam a aparecer do 11 ao 19 e por aí vai.

Tem como será?

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar criar 2 novas variareis e fazer os seguintes cálculos.

- 1º Variável: `Página * Quantidade_de_Página`
- 2º Variável: `(Página * Quantidade_de_Página) - Quantidade_de_Página + 1;`

Ai você vai ter os resultados como você quer. Ex.: Pag 1 de 1 à 10

Comment: Acho que não serve. Por exemplo, se eu tiver 20 páginas e eu estiver na página 9: variável1 = 20*9 = 180 e variável2 = 180-20+1 = 161; pra que eu usaria essas variáveis grandes?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro de tudo, precisa saber a página atual:

```
$currentPage = 2;
```

Após, definir o número de páginas que deseja exibir:

```
$displayedPages = 10;
```

Após, deve encontrar o "meio termo" (ficaria mais fácil se o número de páginas exibidas fosse impar, mas "tanto faz"):

```
$middlePage = ceil($displayedPages / 2);//5 (caso for número impar, arredondará para baixo)
```

Deve definir em que número irá iniciar, pois não pode começar paginações negativas:

```
$startDisplayedPage = $currentPage <= $middlePage ? 1 : $currentPage  - $middlePage + 1;
```

Caso a página corrente for menor que a metade das páginas a serem exibidas (no caso é 5), inicia no número 1. Caso contrário, é a metade + 1 (se a páginas corrente for 10, inicia a contagem 6 e o quinto número é a página corrente).

Entretanto, existe a possibilidade de ser uma página próximo do final da listagem, nesse caso, você também precisa validar:

```
 $total = 70; //total de páginas
```

E, então, validar:

```
 $startDisplayedPage = $startDisplayedPage >= $total - $displayedPages ? ($total - $displayedPages + 1) : $startDisplayedPage;
```

Caso a página inicial for maior que o total menos as páginas a serem mostrar (que no cálculo será 60, deve adicionar 60 + 1, para começar em 61). Caso contrário, iniciar conforme anteriormente calculado.

Agora é partir pra criação dos links:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $displayedPages ; $i++)
{
    $values[] = sprintf(
        '<a href="?page=%1$d" title="Página %1$d">%1$d</a>',
        $startDisplayedPage++ //adiciona a página corrente e, após, incrementa 1
    );
}

echo implode(' | ' , $values);
```

Os valores foram adicionados ao array apenas para questões de impressão/visualização. Mas facilitará o seu processo.

E a saída:

> 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10

Se, por acaso, a página corrente fosse 50:

> 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55

E, se por outro lado, o número de páginas a serem exibidas fosse 11 (ímpar):

> 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55

Caso, a página corrente for 65:

> 61 | 62 | 63 | 64 | 65 | 66 | 67 | 68 | 69 | 70